# How can I color a UIImage in Swift?

Tags: ios, image, swift, colors, uiimage

I have an image called `arrowWhite`. I want to colour this image to black.

```
func attachDropDownArrow() -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    let image:UIImage = UIImage(named: "arrowWhite.png")!
    let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    attachment.image = image
    attachment.bounds = CGRectMake(2.25, 2, attachment.image!.size.width - 2.25, attachment.image!.size.height - 2.25)
    let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
    let myString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: NSString(format: "%@", self.privacyOptions[selectedPickerRow]) as String)
    myString.appendAttributedString(attachmentString)
    return myString
}
```

I want to get this image in `blackColour`.
`tintColor` is not working...

Comment: doable from the Interface Builder, see @Harry Bloom pretty far down below

Comment: Most elegant solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63167556/2692839

Comment: Nowadays it is this easy: **yourIcon.image = yourIcon.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)** then set the tint

Answer (score 241):

**Swift 4 and 5**

```
extension UIImageView {
  func setImageColor(color: UIColor) {
    let templateImage = self.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    self.image = templateImage
    self.tintColor = color
  }
}
```

Call like this:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "your_image_name"))
imageView.setImageColor(color: UIColor.purple)
```

Alternativ 
**For Swift 3, 4 or 5**

```
extension UIImage {

    func maskWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
        let maskImage = cgImage!

        let width = size.width
        let height = size.height
        let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
        let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(width), height: Int(height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)!

        context.clip(to: bounds, mask: maskImage)
        context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context.fill(bounds)

        if let cgImage = context.makeImage() {
            let coloredImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            return coloredImage
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

**For Swift 2.3**

```
extension UIImage {
func maskWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {

    let maskImage = self.CGImage
    let width = self.size.width
    let height = self.size.height
    let bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)

    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)
    let bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, Int(width), Int(height), 8, 0, colorSpace, bitmapInfo.rawValue) //needs rawValue of bitmapInfo

    CGContextClipToMask(bitmapContext, bounds, maskImage)
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(bitmapContext, color.CGColor)
    CGContextFillRect(bitmapContext, bounds)

    //is it nil?
    if let cImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext) {
        let coloredImage = UIImage(CGImage: cImage)

        return coloredImage

    } else {
        return nil
    } 
 }
}
```

Call like this:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "your_image_name")
testImage.image =  image?.maskWithColor(color: UIColor.blue)
```

Comment: Nice start, but the result is grainy. As @Darko mentions below, I believe it is because you are not taking scale and other parameters into account.

Comment: same for me - pixelated image

Comment: Worked prefect for me in Swift 3. Thanks!!

Comment: Doesn't preserve scaling and orientation.

Comment: inside extension, function should be public

Comment: I do not know exactly. The added benefit would be that third parties (pods, libraries ...) could use this extension. If you like you can set this function to public. I do not see any disadvantages for that.

Comment: This solution works but image gets blurry so its useless

Comment: Yeah, poorly thats true. If you use an image with high resolution and use the different layers @2 and @3 it should be okay

Answer (score 98):

There's a built in method to obtain a `UIImage` that is automatically rendered in [template mode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIView-SW17). This uses a view's tintColor to color the image:

```
let templateImage = originalImage.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate)
myImageView.image = templateImage
myImageView.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
```

Comment: This is the best answer - more info may be found in Apple Docs - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIView-SW17

Comment: See Swift 3 syntax for rendering mode here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24145287/448718

Comment: using imageview is obvious, but we want UIImage only

Comment: not a solution if you are working with UIImage objects independently of UIImageView's. This only works if you have access to UIImageView

Comment: Works great even in case when myImageView is a UIButton

Comment: This solution perfectly worked for me & even image retains its quality. Great work.

Comment: you provided method to imageview. i know this. how to do the same with out imageview?

Comment: title is how to color IMAGE, not imageView... :)

Answer (score 50):

First you have to change the rendering property of the image to "Template Image" in the .xcassets folder.
You can then just change the tint color property of the instance of your UIImageView like so:

```
imageView.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

[image]

Comment: Did `tintColor` get removed from `UIImage` at some point? I was excited about this answer, but it doesn't seem to exist in iOS 10

Comment: Hey @TravisGriggs. Sorry, I have just edited my answer to be a bit more descriptive, the tintColor property is on UIImageView, not UIImage

Comment: Tx, this is so cool! Note: The Tint appears in the View section of the ImageView inspector, a little further down. Just to be extra clear.

Answer (score 40):

I ended up with this because other answers either lose resolution or work with UIImageView, not UIImage, or contain unnecessary actions:

**Swift 3**

```
extension UIImage {
    
    public func mask(with color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        
        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size)
        
        color.setFill()
        self.draw(in: rect)
        
        context.setBlendMode(.sourceIn)
        context.fill(rect)
        
        let resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return resultImage
    }
    
}
```

Comment: best answer in here, keeps the same image orientation and quality

Comment: Yeah, I've tested all the above answers and this indeed takes the scale into consideration, so it won't give you pixelated `UIImage`s. Really nice answer, thank you!

Comment: If you have an image with a transparent background, you can set blend mode to .destinationAtop. This lets you color the foreground of the image, leaving the background untouched.

Comment: This is the best answer if you are working with just UIImages and not UIViews.

Answer (score 23):

This function uses core graphics to achieve this.

```
func overlayImage(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    color.setFill()

    context!.translateBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height)
    context!.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

    context!.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.colorBurn)
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)
    context!.draw(self.cgImage!, in: rect)

    context!.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.sourceIn)
    context!.addRect(rect)
    context!.drawPath(using: CGPathDrawingMode.fill)

    let coloredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return coloredImage
}
```

Comment: This works, where the other top two answers are wrong.

Comment: Yes this works perfectly. `maskWithColor ` extension works but that ignores `scale` so image does not look sharp on higher resolution devices.

Comment: This works perfect!! We use in a extension and runs OK. Others solutions ignore scale...

Answer (score 20):

**For swift 4.2 to change UIImage color as you want (solid color)**

```
extension UIImage {
    func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)
        color.setFill()

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.translateBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height)
        context?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)

        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))
        context?.clip(to: rect, mask: self.cgImage!)
        context?.fill(rect)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage!
    }
}
```

**How to use**

```
self.imgVw.image = UIImage(named: "testImage")?.imageWithColor(UIColor.red)
```

Answer (score 11):

I found the solution by H R to be most helpful but adapted it slightly for Swift 3

```
extension UIImage {

    func maskWithColor( color:UIColor) -> UIImage {

         UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
         let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

         color.setFill()

         context.translateBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height)
         context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

         let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)
         context.draw(self.cgImage!, in: rect)

         context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.sourceIn)
         context.addRect(rect)
         context.drawPath(using: CGPathDrawingMode.fill)

         let coloredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
         UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

         return coloredImage!
    }
}
```

This takes into consideration scale and also does not produce a lower res image like some other solutions. 
Usage :

```
image = image.maskWithColor(color: .green )
```

Comment: This is definitely the implementation to use (disambiguating from other ones on this page).

Comment: To be extra safe the force unwraps should be wrapped in if-lets or a guard.

Answer (score 10):

Create an extension on UIImage:

```
/// UIImage Extensions
extension UIImage {
    func maskWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {

        var maskImage = self.CGImage
        let width = self.size.width
        let height = self.size.height
        let bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)
        let bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, Int(width), Int(height), 8, 0, colorSpace, bitmapInfo)

        CGContextClipToMask(bitmapContext, bounds, maskImage)
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(bitmapContext, color.CGColor)
        CGContextFillRect(bitmapContext, bounds)

        let cImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext)
        let coloredImage = UIImage(CGImage: cImage)

        return coloredImage!
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like that:

```
image.maskWithColor(UIColor.redColor())
```

Comment: This ignores `scale`, `orientation` and other parameters of `UIImage`.

Answer (score 9):

For iOS13+ there are [withTintColor(__:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/3327300-withtintcolor) and [withTintColor(_:renderingMode:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/3327301-withtintcolor) methods.

Example usage:

```
let newImage = oldImage.withTintColor(.red)
```

or

```
let newImage = oldImage.withTintColor(.red, renderingMode: .alwaysTemplate)
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3 extension wrapper from @Nikolai Ruhe answer.

```
extension UIImageView {

    func maskWith(color: UIColor) {
        guard let tempImage = image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate) else { return }
        image = tempImage
        tintColor = color
    }

}
```

It can be use for `UIButton` as well, e.g:

```
button.imageView?.maskWith(color: .blue)
```

Answer (score 6):

Add this extension in your code and change image color in storyboard itself.

**Swift 4 & 5:**

```
extension UIImageView {
    @IBInspectable
    var changeColor: UIColor? {
        get {
            let color = UIColor(cgColor: layer.borderColor!);
            return color
        }
        set {
            let templateImage = self.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
            self.image = templateImage
            self.tintColor = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Storyboard Preview:**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4**

```
 let image: UIImage? =  #imageLiteral(resourceName: "logo-1").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    topLogo.image = image
    topLogo.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Answer (score 5):

## Simpleminded way:

```
yourIcon.image = yourIcon.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
yourIcon.tintColor = .someColor
```

### BTW it's more fun on Android!

```
yourIcon.setColorFilter(getColor(R.color.someColor), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Very straightforward solution!

Comment: @chlkdst - right, nowadays **it is very easy.**  A huge problem with Stackoverflow is that,  you get answers which change drastically over the many years.  This question is some ten years old - the answers from that era are of no value now.  It's a difficult problem on SO.

Answer (score 4):

Add extension Function:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func setImage(named: String, color: UIColor) {
        self.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: named).withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.tintColor = color
    }
}
```

Use like:

```
anyImageView.setImage(named: "image_name", color: .red)
```

Answer (score 2):

Post iOS 13 you can use it something like this

```
arrowWhiteImage.withTintColor(.black, renderingMode: .alwaysTemplate)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 3

#### 21 June 2017

I use CALayer to mask the given image with Alpha Channel

```
import Foundation


extension UIImage {

    func maskWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
    
        let maskLayer = CALayer()
        maskLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        maskLayer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
        maskLayer.doMask(by: self)
        let maskImage = maskLayer.toImage()
        return maskImage
    }

}


extension CALayer {
    func doMask(by imageMask: UIImage) {
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageMask.size.width, height: imageMask.size.height)
        bounds = maskLayer.bounds
        maskLayer.contents = imageMask.cgImage
        maskLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)
        mask = maskLayer
    }

    func toImage() -> UIImage?
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size,
                                               isOpaque,
                                               UIScreen.main.scale)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return nil
        }
        render(in: context)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 version with scale and Orientation from @kuzdu answer

```
extension UIImage {

    func mask(_ color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
        let maskImage = cgImage!

        let width = (cgImage?.width)!
        let height = (cgImage?.height)!
        let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
        let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(width), height: Int(height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)!

        context.clip(to: bounds, mask: maskImage)
        context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context.fill(bounds)

        if let cgImage = context.makeImage() {
            let coloredImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: imageOrientation)
            return coloredImage
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.**

Use this extension to create a **solid colored image**

```
extension UIImage {   

    public func coloredImage(color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
        return coloredImage(color: color, size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
    }

    public func coloredImage(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)

        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(CGRect(origin: CGPoint(), size: size))

        guard let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return nil }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return image
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked prefect for me in navigationBar.setBackgroundImage and Swift 5. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is swift 3 version of H R's solution.

```
func overlayImage(color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    color.setFill()

    context!.translateBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height)
    context!.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

    context!.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.colorBurn)
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)
    context!.draw(self.cgImage!, in: rect)

    context!.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.sourceIn)
    context!.addRect(rect)
    context!.drawPath(using: CGPathDrawingMode.fill)

    let coloredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return coloredImage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the tint color of UIImage.
Use simple two-line code:

```
ImageView.image = ImageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
ImageView.tintColor = UIColor.black
```

Where image view is your image outlet.

Answer (score -1):

Since I found Darko's answer very helpful in colorizing custom pins for mapView annotations, but had to do some conversions for Swift 3, thought I'd share the updated code along with my recommendation for his answer:

```
extension UIImage {
    func maskWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {

        var maskImage = self.CGImage
        let width = self.size.width
        let height = self.size.height
        let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
        let bitmapContext = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(width), height: Int(height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)

        bitmapContext!.clip(to: bounds, mask: maskImage!)
        bitmapContext!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        bitmapContext!.fill(bounds)

        let cImage = bitmapContext!.makeImage()
        let coloredImage = UIImage(CGImage: cImage)

        return coloredImage!
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have modified the extension found here: [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/iamjason/a0a92845094f5b210cf8), for `Swift 3` which I have tested in the context of an extension for UIImage.

```
func tint(with color: UIColor) -> UIImage 
{
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size)
   guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return self }

   // flip the image
   context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
   context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: -self.size.height)

   // multiply blend mode
   context.setBlendMode(.multiply)

   let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)
   context.clip(to: rect, mask: self.cgImage!)
   color.setFill()
   context.fill(rect)

   // create UIImage
   guard let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return self }
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

   return newImage
}
```

Comment: works fine, work in swift 5.x AND answer to question ! :)