# Changing the color of a gif in Swift

Tags: ios, swift3

I need to change the color of a gif programatically. The original gif is white on clear background, and I want to make it change color through code.

I've tried the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803157/how-to-color-a-uiimage-in-swift), but that causes the gif to freeze on the first frame. Here's some of the code I'm working with.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        myImageView?.image = UIImage.gif(name: "my_gif")
        myImageView?.image = myImageView?.image?.maskWithColor(color: UIColor.red)
        // This creates a red, but still version of the gif
    }
}

extension UIImage {

    func maskWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
        let maskImage = cgImage!

        let width = size.width
        let height = size.height
        let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
        let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(width), height: Int(height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)!

        context.clip(to: bounds, mask: maskImage)
        context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context.fill(bounds)

        if let cgImage = context.makeImage() {
            let coloredImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            return coloredImage
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

I'm currently using different gif files for each color I need as a workaround, but that sounds awfully inefficient. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `UIView` and set it's background color. Then you can set the view's alpha value to 0.5 and place the view over the image view.

Like so:

```
let overlayView = UIView()
overlayView.frame = myImageView.frame
overlayView.backgroundColor = .red
overlayView.alpha = 0.5
view.addSubview(overlayView)
```

This way your not messing up the existing image view that works.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wouldn't that create a red translucent rectangle over the gif? What I'm trying to do is change the white in the original to red, while keeping the clear background.

Comment: Oh yeah that's exactly what that would do. Sorry about that. The reason that your posted code _freezes_ is case your setting the image of the image view to a single `UIImage`. Your code first sets the image of the image view to an animated sequence I assume then right after you set a single image for the image view. To solve this you'd need to apply the tinting code in your extension to each image in your GIF.