# How to set tint color of an Image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, tintcolor

```
let tintedImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user")
pictureImageView?.image = mainCircleImage.overlayed(with: tintedImage,color: UIColor.orange)

extension UIImage {
func overlayed(with overlay: UIImage,color:UIColor) -> UIImage? {
    defer {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
    self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))
    let tintedOverlay = overlay.tintedImageWithColor(color: color)
    tintedOverlay.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))
    if let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
        return image
    }
    return nil
}

func tint(color: UIColor, blendMode: CGBlendMode) -> UIImage
{
    let drawRect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    context!.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    context!.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: -self.size.height)
    context!.clip(to: drawRect, mask: cgImage!)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(drawRect)
    draw(in: drawRect, blendMode: blendMode, alpha: 1.0)
    let tintedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return tintedImage!
}

func tintedImageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage
{
    return self.tint(color: color, blendMode: CGBlendMode.multiply)
}
}
```

I have updated my question according to possible answer
Here is my code for the changing the icon color. In some reason my user icon is not fully filling its color when i change the tint color.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to color a UIImage in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803157/how-to-color-a-uiimage-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had added 2 more methods to your extension of `UIImage`for tint an Image and added some changes in your `overlayed` method

```
extension UIImage {
    func overlayed(with overlay: UIImage,color:UIColor) -> UIImage? {
        defer {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))
        let tintedOverlay = overlay.tinted(color: color)
        tintedOverlay.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size), blendMode: .multiply, alpha: 1.0)
        if let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
            return image
        }
        return nil
    }

    func tinted(color: UIColor) -> UIImage
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        color.setFill()

        context!.translateBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height)
        context!.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

        context!.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.colorBurn)
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)
        context!.draw(self.cgImage!, in: rect)

        context!.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.sourceIn)
        context!.addRect(rect)
        context!.drawPath(using: CGPathDrawingMode.fill)

        let coloredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return coloredImage!
    }
}
```

> The content of Tinted method is from this question [How can I color a UIImage in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803157/how-can-i-color-a-uiimage-in-swift)
>   answer provided by @HR

**Use It**

```
    let mainCircleImage = UIImage(named: "actions_menu_edit")?
    let tintedImage = UIImage(named: "actions_menu_add")
    pictureImageView?.image = mainCircleImage?.overlayed(with: tintedImage!,color: UIColor.red)
```

## UPDATED

**Result with the last update**

[image]

Comment: @DicleY change the tint color in the imageView where you are putting your image with .alwaysTemplate rendering mode

Comment: in some reason its keep making my changed tint image as black always which ever color i give..   @ReinierMelian

Comment: what does your overlayed `UIImageView` extension method method?

Comment: I have added it as well to my question

Comment: @DicleY you are trying to draw 2 images one in top of another and add a tin color to the second one? is this what you need to do?

Comment: yes i would like to change "user" image's tint color it is subview of the other imageView(circle_icon). I just want to change "user" 's tint color.

Comment: humm it worked 80%.. but weirdly my tint color is not fully red. there are some black dots inside of that new color...

Comment: @DicleY update your question with your current code in order to review it and see what can be wrong this time

Comment: I just did. Tried to add the image but not sure if its visible

Comment: Yes I can see it @DicleY i will review it

Comment: @DicleY can you post your two original images to test in my enviroment?

Comment: @DicleY I will review it

Comment: @DicleY sorry but you can post the user image on better resolution?

Comment: i did now can you have a look or i can give higher higher one again

Comment: @DicleY check my updated answer the problem is the blendMode for your case should be .overlay

Comment: Thats better when i set red etc. but when i set UIColor.orange its showing 2 different colors again..

Comment: Thats so weird its only showing itself for light orange color.. there is nothing wrong with red

Comment: @DicleY yes I see, well I will check again ;)

Comment: @DicleY it seems a bug or something its very wierd, I think is related to the image itself

Comment: @DicleY check my last update I had founded in another SO answer