# Need to Change value with UIColor for UIImage

Tags: swift, swift3

I Cloned bacon testing application on github in this application they add 3 UIColors with value in array so I need to change that UIColor tips for UI Image type any one please help me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axajh.jpg)

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this extension:

```
   extension UIImageView {
      func setImageColor(color: UIColor) {
        let templateImage = self.image?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
        self.image = templateImage
        self.tintColor = color
      }
    }

let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "your_image_name"))
imageView.setImageColor(color: UIColor.purple)
```

Reference link: [How can I color a UIImage in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803157/how-can-i-color-a-uiimage-in-swift)