# Set UIImageView tintColor with multiple colors

Tags: ios, swift

[image: ,]

I have this png image.
How can I change this blue color (only) to a different color in swift. 
This because I might need to change to many different colors. 
Even better if its possible to change the black color to white.

Comment: Possible functionality is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803157/how-can-i-color-a-uiimage-in-swift/36591030

Comment: This still only change the entire colored pixel to one color. Anyone have any ideal to achieve this? Like using svg file or something. I have done this in android by using LightingColorFilter.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
    self.img.image = self.img.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    self.img.tintColor = UIColor.black
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let tableImage: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView()
    image.image = image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    image.tintColor = .white
    return image
}()
```

try this, this will change your image tintColor. I don't think you can set mutiple colors in image