# How to fill image with color?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a png image which i want to fill with color.

I know about tint color, but it color only borders, i need to color inside the borders, like this desired result

**Here I showed what I want to achieve**

[image]

Comment: Make it as `pdf` with black color.

Comment: try this https://github.com/exyte/macaw

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I color a UIImage in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803157/how-can-i-color-a-uiimage-in-swift)

Comment: i edited picture to make more clear what i mean under fill image with color. It is not exactly image i want to fill - it is closed empty space in image.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below codes,

```
extension UIImageView {
  func setImageColor(color: UIColor) {
    let templateImage = self.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    self.image = templateImage
    self.tintColor = color
  }
}
```

And you can call like:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "your_image_name"))
imageView.setImageColor(color: UIColor.purple)
```

Referred from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36591030/2907715)

Comment: This is not a solution for the question above.