# Coloring a WKInterfaceImage?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm using this code which works well on iPhone but I need to color a WKImage in WatchKit, how can I do this? I tried using the same code for an Extension on WKInterfaceImage but the `image` property is get only.

```
extension UIImageView {
    func setImageColor(color: UIColor) {
        let templateImage = self.image?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
        self.image = templateImage
        self.tintColor = color
    }
}
```

[How can I color a UIImage in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803157/how-can-i-color-a-uiimage-in-swift)