# Display an UIImage in SwitfUI is dark - Apple Watch

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I do not understand why the car systemName image does not appear on Apple Watch Simulator. (it is black)

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: "car")!)
    }
}

struct preview : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[Click here to see how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/py7V7.png) (the screen is completely black, like if nothing was added to the view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose it should be

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "car") // < Native SwiftUI
    }
}
```

or... if you so like `UIImage`, the same result with

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: "car")!).colorInvert()
```

Comment: @FirsfNameLastname out of curiosity, why UIImage? To share across a UIKit target?

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to set the UIImage color to white, like that it will be visible

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: "car")!.maskWithColor(color: .white)!)
```

where maskWithColor comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/36591030/12893419

```
extension UIImage {

    func maskWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
        let maskImage = cgImage!

        let width = size.width
        let height = size.height
        let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
        let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(width), height: Int(height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)!

        context.clip(to: bounds, mask: maskImage)
        context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context.fill(bounds)

        if let cgImage = context.makeImage() {
            let coloredImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            return coloredImage
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```